# iPhone 4 GSM 3,1 upgrade

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I'm using iOS 5.1.1 (9B206). I want to upgrade my iPhone to iOS 6.1.3, but I don't know how to do this. I have tried downloading the IPSW of iOS 6.1.3 to upgrade, but it doesn't make any changes. The second time, I try building file SHSH with IPSW, but that didn't work either. Any ideas for this problem to upgrade from 5.1.1 (9B206) to ios 6.1.3 ?

Comment: Why don't you want to upgrade to iOS 7? I would assume this would be an easier upgrade.

Comment: It was great to upgrade to iOS 7, but i found my friends using this version 7.1 didn't enjoy it. So i prefer lower version instead !

Comment: 7.1 runs way better than 7.0, you should consider it also because of security reasons.

Comment: As noted by @AndrewLarsson this is the same scenario as downgrading to an old iOS build that isn't signed and approved by Apple any more; you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't upgrade to another version other than the latest iOS version, as your iPhone requires to have the software verified with the apple servers to sign it.

There use to be a fix to this by blocking the connection of iTunes with Apple server or diverting it to a custom server but this can't be done anymore.

So your best bet is to continue using iOS 5.1.1 or upgrade to 7.1.1